# read data for every 100 days untill we get the complete data in hive

Tags: database, bash, unix, hive, bigdata

I am copying data from prod to test for testing purpose in hive using bash script. when i am doing so for a table , I have received a memory heap issue.
to solve this , I am planning to read the data from rundate (day when i am executing the script) to the day where the data available for every 100 days to avoid this issue. can you please let me know how to achieve this using bash and please do let me know if is there any other approach other than setting up the memory

Comment: Share and example, and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Hi Lohit,Thank you for the response. am trying to compare the counts of prod with test after copying millions of records from table A of prod db to table A ofTest db. since i am seeing issue in executing the query , I am trying to do count for every 100 days of data from today rundate to the date the data available and will compare against the test db to ensure all the data are copied.

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to run a HiveQL(.hql) script from shell.

Create a `.hql` script with your query of pulling only last 100 days of data.

`example.hql`

```
select * from my_database.my_table 
where insert_date BETWEEN '2018-07-01' AND '2018-10-01';
```

Now you can call this script from hive shell:
`hive -f example.hql`

Or you can create a shell script and execute your query in it.
`run.sh`

```
    #!/bin/bash
    hive -e "select * from my_database.my_table 
    where insert_date BETWEEN '2018-07-01' AND '2018-10-01'" >select.txt

    result=`echo $?`
    if [ $result -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Error!!!!"
    echo "Hive error number is: $result"
    exit 1
    else
    echo "no error, do your stuffs"
    fi
```

Then execute your shell script by `sh run.sh`.